# Spacing timestamp in pandas plot using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

Please my code is shown below. I want to space the timestamp as the plot looks so squeezed.

```
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd

    dataset = pd.read_csv('../Data/User/DataSample.csv')
    dataset.head(10)

        Grade   Time
0   Pass    2020-02-13 13:24:56
1   Pass    2020-02-13 13:25:00
2   Pass    2020-02-13 13:25:04
3   Pass    2020-02-13 13:25:08
4   Pass    2020-02-13 13:25:13
5   Pass    2020-02-13 13:25:17
6   Pass    2020-02-13 13:25:21
7   Pass    2020-02-13 13:25:27
8   Pass    2020-02-13 13:25:31
9   Pass    2020-02-13 13:26:19

    sns.scatterplot(x='Time', y='Grade', hue='Grade', data=dataset)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

[Result of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkeTU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for including a sample dataset.

Give this a shot:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = sns.scatterplot(x='Time',y='Grade',hue='Grade',data=df)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The x-axis values do not show on the plot

Comment: @Goddy: that is odd. I am getting x-axis tick labels with the above code.

Comment: I can't figure out why the labels are not showing. Please which editor are you using? I am using "Jupiter". I tried to change the HourLocator() to MinuteLocator but still not show.

Comment: I'm using ipython.